# Query Hardware-Specific Information on Windows With C++

Tags: hardware, gpu, bios

Specifically, I want to query a system's GPU for the following:

The name of the GPU, the series (e.g. ATI Radion 5800, NVIDIA GeForce 4 MX, etc.), the BIOS version, the driver version, the GPU clock speed, the GPU memory speed, the memory type, the memory size, the bus width, the bandwidth, the type of bus being used, the vendor.

Any ideas? The application I'm developing just has to display this information to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest querying WMI, using the following WMI objects:

**Win32_DisplayConfiguration**
- name of GPU

**Win32_VideoController**
- DAC type, speed
- video RAM size

also try:

**CIM_VideoBIOSFeature**
**CIM_VideoBIOSElement**